# Does the generated ipa expires?

Tags: ios

I have generated ipa from [diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com) of my application.

But I want to know that does the generated ipa of my application expires after some time interval.

Because as of now I don't have my project I have only the generated ipa with me.

So if anybody knows please tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience - this validity is connected with the expiration date of any Provisioning Profiles and sign certificates used with that .ipa. If provisioning expires, so does the .ipa.

Answer (score 1):

Ipa file will not expire till provisional profile is working. If provisional profile expires then you will not able to install ipa to device.